# AngularJS watching service variable from directive, how to correctly implement factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to watch angular factory variable from inside directive, and act upon change.

I must be missing something fundamental from Javascript, but can someone explain, why approach (1) using inline object works, and approach (2) using prototyping does not?

Does prototype somehow hide `user` variable scope from angular $watch?

How can i make this code more clean?

(1):
[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2cjA6GMFX1Cp5NYAkN35?p=preview)

```
 angular.module('testApp', [
      ])
      .factory('myUser', [function () {
         var userService = {};
         var user = {id : Date.now()};
         userService.get = function() {
           return user;
         };
         userService.set = function(newUser) {
           user = newUser;
         };
        return userService;
      }])
      .directive('userId',['myUser',function(myUser) {
        return {
          restrict : 'A',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(myUser.get, function(newUser) {
              if(newUser) {
                elm.text(newUser.id);
              }
            });
          }
        };
      }])
      .controller('ChangeCtrl', ['myUser', '$scope',function(myUser, $scope) {
        $scope.change = function() {
          myUser.set({id: Date.now()});
        };
      }]);
```

(2):
[Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MEis5MMN9BLXxrmy58cF?p=preview)

```
 angular.module('testApp', [
      ])
      .factory('myUser', [function () {

         var user = {id : Date.now()};
         var UserService = function(initial) {
            this.user = initial;
         }
         UserService.prototype.get = function() {
           return this.user;
         };
         UserService.prototype.set = function(newUser) {
           this.user = newUser;
         };
        return new UserService(user);
      }])
      .directive('userId',['myUser',function(myUser) {
        return {
          restrict : 'A',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(myUser.get, function(newUser) {
              //this watch does not fire
              if(newUser) {
                elm.text(newUser.id);
              }
            });
          }
        };
      }])
      .controller('ChangeCtrl', ['myUser', '$scope',function(myUser, $scope) {
        $scope.change = function() {
          myUser.set({id: Date.now()});
        };
      }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1:**

`myUser.get` function reference is called without a context (`return user`), and the `user` object is returned as a closure variable.

**Case 2:**

`myUser.get` function reference is called without a context (`return this.user`), and so `this.user` only just don't throw an error because you are not in "strict mode" where `this` is pointing to the `window` object, thus resulting in `this.user` being just `undefined`.

What you actually missed is the fact that giving `myUser.get` as a watcher check function is giving a reference to a function, which will not be applied to `myUser` as a context when used by the watcher.

Answer (score 0):

As i remember angular watches only properties belonging to the object.
The watch function does this by checking the property with hasOwnProperty